# what is the best way to do server side asp.net mvc filtering of jqgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, filtering

I have an action that is tied to jqgrid filtering.

right now i have something like this.

```
    public ActionResult GridData(GridData args)
    {
              IEnumerable<Car> car = model.GetCars();
             // now i need to filter and return a Json object.
     }
```

In my case i have a collection or car objects.  Is there best practices to have filtering without having a big select case around each field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a great blog on the subject

http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/tag/jqgrid/

Comment: This link is not active now

Comment: @Satheesh  Not much I can do about this.  Craig is a previous collegue and it seems that the blog mentioned in the post has been discontinued.